# how to assign echo value to a variable in shell

Tags: shell, unix

Im tring to assign echo value which to a variable but im getting error

```
Var='(echo $2 | sed -e 's/,/: chararray /g'|  sed -e 's/$/: chararray/')'
echo $var

Input :  sh load.sh file 1,2,3,4
Error load.sh: line 1: chararray: command not found
```

Comment: you got your quotes messed up.

Comment: You can't nest quotes like that (and can't escape single quotes inside single quotes). Also you need `$()` to run a command and don't need quotes on the right-hand side of an assignment.

Comment: Also, shell variables are case sensitive.

Comment: You can reduce your 2 sed commands to one: `sed -e 's/,\|$/: chararray /g'` -- that is, replace all commas or end of string with the replacement text.

Comment: @glennjackman: (1) the replacement strings are different, so there need to be two separate `-e 's/…/…/'` expressions on the one `sed` command, and (2) the `|` notation in the regex only works when `sed` supports it, and `sed` may need to be told to allow it (`-E` or `-r` options); not all versions of `sed` support extended regular expressions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Var=$(echo "$2" | sed -e 's/,/: chararray /g' | sed -e 's/$/: chararray/')
echo "$Var"
```

OR

```
Var=`echo "$2" | sed -e 's/,/: chararray /g' | sed -e 's/$/: chararray/'`
echo "$Var"
```

Use either `$(…)` or perhaps `` `…` `` backtick notation. However, the backtick notation is deprecated and should be avoided. Also, check the comments by [mmgross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010999/how-to-assign-echo-value-to-a-variable-in-shell#comment46267668_29010999), [Etan Reisner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29010999/how-to-assign-echo-value-to-a-variable-in-shell#comment46268668_29010999) and [svlasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1005230/svlasov) to your question. They are all correct.